# Trying to connect to Twitter Streaming API using ROAuth, getting "Error: Forbidden"

Tags: twitter-oauth, roauth

I'm trying to use StreamR to get a stream of tweets originating from a particular location. Before I do that, I'm required to do a handshake using ROAuth. Here is what I do:

```
reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "FCVbysnkgqLGAwlkgVTuQA9BJ"
consumerSecret <- "x5wA44qtm5Fj5OD1V1O9qYsWfdgLzQxRfpxqVIpzdEZE7FPJGe"
my_oauth <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                             consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                             requestURL=reqURL,
                             accessURL=accessURL,
                             authURL=authURL)

my_oauth$handshake()
```

When `my_oauth$handshake()` executes and I copy the PIN, I get `Error: Forbidden`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `http`s to `https`es and it worked.